# Как корректно сохранить цветной текст в файл?

Tags: java, swing

Есть методы изменения цвета выделенного текста.

```
 // выбираем цвет
 private void showColorChooser() {

    colorChooser = new JColorChooser();
    if (textColor == null) {
        textColor = Color.BLACK;
    }
    textColor = colorChooser.showDialog(null, "Цвет текста", textColor);
    colorChoseButton.setBackground(textColor);
    colorChoseButton.setForeground(textColor);
    if (textPane.getSelectedText() == null) {
        textPane.setForeground(textColor);
    }
}
// меняем цвет текста
private void changeTextColor(Color c) {
    document = textPane.getStyledDocument();


    SimpleAttributeSet colorSeter = new SimpleAttributeSet();

    StyleConstants.setForeground(colorSeter, c);
    document.setCharacterAttributes(textPane.getSelectionStart(), textPane.getSelectionEnd() - textPane.getSelectionStart(), colorSeter, true);
    textColor = colorChoseButton.getBackground();
    textPane.setSelectedTextColor(textColor);
}
```

Есть метод `saveFileAs();`

```
    private void saveFileAs (){
    JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    fileChooser.showDialog(null,"Save");
    file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
    if (fileChooser.getSelectedFile()==null || textPane.getText()==null){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Файл не выбран или пуст");
    } else {
        try {
            outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            outputStream.write(textPane.getText().getBytes());
        } catch (IOException ex){}
    }
}
```

Я меняю цвет текста и сохраняю его в файл формата .dock. Открываю файл с помощью word и его цвет черный (не поменянный). Как это исправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А вы методом changeTextColor точно меняйте цвет в документе(данных) а не в панеле? 
Посмотрите по спецификации формата .doc как должны быть оформлены цвета для текста.

Comment: @KonstantinEmelyanov точно в документе. Я строкой 

document = textPane.getStyledDocument(); беру стиль документа, а строкой document.setCharacterAttributes(textPane.getSelectionStart(), textArea.getSelectionEnd() - textPane.getSelectionStart(), colorSeter, true); меняю данные в нем

Comment: @KonstantinEmelyanov А в чем смысл таких действий? Word отлаженная программа, он поменяет мне цвет, а моя программа — нет. Я же на скрине показал

Comment: А почему вы решили, что `JTextArea` умеет сохранять документы в формате doc? Метод `getText()` возвращает обычную строку и создаете вы обычный текстовый файл

Comment: @AntonShchyrov у меня JTextPane используется. Сохраняю я, вводя расширение в JFileChooser

Comment: А если вы укажете расширение `avi`, то у вас видео файл получится?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Файл сохраняется, но его не удается воспроизвести, что логично.

Comment: doc - это вам не txt, тут все сложнее. хотите работать с пакетом офиса - не проблема, нo не с помощью textPane. К примеру , для создания такого файла можно использовать Apache POI

Comment: @Дмитрий а если я сохраню в txt то цветного текста не получу)) А мне бы проверить работает ли форматирование.

Comment: Ну так при указании расширения `doc` файл тоже сохраняется, но не воспроизводится. Или это уже не логично?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov doc воспроизводится. Но форматирования строки не происходит, сейчас добавлю скриншот, что он у меня есть и открылся

Comment: @AntonShchyrov добавил

Comment: у вас не doc сохраняется. тот же результат вы получите, если сохраните файл txt , а потом поменяете расширение на doc

Comment: @Дмитрий а как сохранить, к примеру, rtf? Чтобы был форматированный текст?

Comment: например, с помощью этого https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.zensols.jrtf/tutego.jrtf

Comment: @Дмитрий а стандартными средствами Swing нельзя? Если так, то странно, форматировать можно, а сохранять результат работы — нет))

Comment: Swing  - библиотека для создания графического интерфейса. такая же, как, например, JavaFX (новее, чем Swing)или AWT (еще более древняя, чем Swing). никакого отношения ни к каким форматам это не имеет. и к сохранению тоже. это просто графика - создание пользовательского интерфейса. разумеется, вы можете форматировать текст , потому как это часть пользовательского интерфейса. посему ничего странного здесь нет))

Comment: кстати, попробуйте сохранить файл на диск в txt и посмотрите в импортах над классом, какие классы джава вы используете. увидите, что никакого свинга там и близко нет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итак, я использовал старую версию [jrtf](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.zensols.jrtf/tutego.jrtf) для создания rtf файла. [Документация по jrtf на GitHub](https://github.com/ullenboom/jrtf) Теперь метод `saveFileAs` выглядит следующим образом:

```
 private void saveFileAs (){
    JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    fileChooser.showDialog(null,"Сохранить файл");
    file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
    if (fileChooser.getSelectedFile()==null || textArea.getText()==null){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Файл не выбран или пуст");
    } else {
        try {
            int R = textColor.getRed();
            int G = textColor.getGreen();
            int B = textColor.getBlue();



            rtf().header(color(R, G, B).at(0))
                    .section(p (color(0, text(textArea.getText())))).out(new FileWriter(file));

            } catch (IOException ex){}
    }
}
```

и сохраняется форматированный текст.
 [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь дело за малым.
   P.S. Спасибо [@Дмитрий](http://user:269255)